# Why does the dynamic sql statement erroring

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to run the Dynamic SQL Query and get the output in the cursor. How to rewrite this statement?

```
OPEN ecur_SS FOR
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'select sSQLQUERY FROM DUAL';
END;
```

sSQLQUERY has my select statement.

```
sSQL := 'SELECT  * from forms' ;
```

ecur_SS is out sys_refcursor

I am getting the following error:

> Error: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "IMMEDIATE" when expecting
>   one of the following:
>       . ( * @ % & = - + ; < / > at in is mod remainder not rem
>        <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like like2
>       like4 likec between using || multiset member submultiset The symbol "* was inserted before "IMMEDIATE" to continue.

Comment: We need the whole PL/SQL block.

Comment: There is more than one mistake in your code. This is your string: `select sSQLQUERY FROM DUAL`. If you run it, Oracle will tell you that there is no column called `sSQLQUERY` in the table `DUAL`. Then, `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` runs a statement, but if you run a select statement, then you must tell Oracle where to put the result. So rather than only show us your code and tell us it doesn't run, please tell us what you want to achieve with it.

Comment: I was trying to paste here.It gives some formatting errors and not allowing me to paste.

Comment: The syntax for opening a cursor for a dynamic SQL string is simply `OPEN ecur_SS FOR sSQL`. But are you even sure you need dynamic SQL? It is not often needed. What do you want your code to do?

Comment: OPEN ecur_SS FOR sSQL; worked.Thank You